# 3-D Secure на мобильных устройствах

Tags: android, ios, безопасность, платежи

Как, например, в Uber реализован процесс добавления банковской карты?

Форма ввода данных карты как я могу понять у них своя, но вот как реализовано подтверждение по СМС? Я так понимаю это 3-D Secure, но ведь он подразумевает открытие страницы в браузере, а в Uber надо просто набрать цифры в их форме.
Я так понимаю у них какой то индивидуальный договор, и им дали разрешение писать 3-D Secure код в свою форму?

Comment: по моему fabric такое поддерживает